# Schrödinger's wonder

Tags: civilization-5

I just had to construct a wonder I already finished. Or did I?

The following confuses me a bit:

[image: East India Company finished, or not]

Either I finished it and I no longer need to construct it, or I still need to construct it and can't have it finished. For some reason my wonder is both constructed and still in progress (Schrödinger's wonder?). How do I avoid such a situation in the future?

This occurred during a simultaneous multi-player Civ V game (incl. DLC).

Comment: I've noticed with multiplayer that the game can get confused when you have enough production to finish that turn.  You might be able to mouse over your city's gold generation to verify if the building is contributing or not.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I suspect it wasn't, since it took another turn to complete the building. On the other hand, I never received the notification of having finished the wonder. Not even the 'second' time I finished it.

Comment: Are you using Enhanced UI?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I have no clue what that is, so, uh, no?

Comment: @Kelexin I posted this question 2 weeks ago and it was a multi-player game not hosted by my. I have no idea whether there still is such a log and where it is.

Answer (score 4):

Did you happen to build or conquer a new city that turn? The cost of the wonder goes up the more cities you have, so maybe you increased the cost on the same turn it should have been completed?

Comment: This sounds like the most probable explanation so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a new city or conquer one (without the needed building in it) and you are currently building the national wonder, then the production cost goes up and you are no longer able to build it, as you don't have the required buildings to complete it.

As for seeing finished, that is just something Civ V does, devs don't care and it doesn't really cause an issue. Most people just see it as oh it finished working, because it can't work on it more right now.

My usual work around is either paying attention to national wonders to avoid settling/conquering for the turn or two it has left. OR just immediately buying the necessary building(s) to resume wonder production.